# Socket.io: Why is htmlfile preferred to XHR-Polling?

Tags: internet-explorer, node.js, socket.io, comet

Based on socket.io 0.9.10 default config [1](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/manager.js#L38), `htmlfile` has higher priority over `xhr-polling`.

I had this idea that `xhr-polling` (aka long poolling) was a natural choice over `websockets` when it is not supported. If I keep `htmlfile` on list, it will be the selected transport for IE6, 7, 8 and 9.

My min req is IE7+, so should I remove `htmlfile`? I tested `xhr-polling` on IE7 and 9 and it works fine.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

htmlfile streams the data, whereas XHR-Polling is request based, so it's possible for htmlfile to be more efficient. This site has a good explanation of each transport.

http://showmetheco.de/articles/2011/8/socket-io-for-backend-developers.html

Comment: Great! It seems that `htmlfile` only works (or works better) on IE:  "Htmlfile is a tranport for Internet Explorer (read "some nasty hacks follow").".... Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, I had problems using htmlfile with IE9 and web antivirus software (e.g. Avira Webguard). the sockets took around 30 seconds to reach the server.

Switching to XHR solved the problem, so I suggest you take that into consideration because many users have all kinds of internet protection software installed.

Comment: Hi @samson. I had a similar problem with antivirus and to solve that we used secure websockets (wss://). It's even a advise in the WS specification.

Comment: right, but the problem was only with IE9 and IE9 doesn t support websockets, so the fallback was the natural thing to do I guess.

Comment: I also read that using port 443 was more reliable. https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Socket.IO-and-firewall-software